# Load Excel data set in processing and use it to draw sphere

Tags: processing

I'm a beginner and would like to know how I can generate a sphere in processing using a small data set. Sort of like a pie chart but in a sphere. I was able to load the dataset. Either create the sphere using product so you'll have 10 distributions or using category where you sum up the categories and create 3 distro. Thanks in advance.
Data:

Product Sales   Category
1   7353784 1
2   745551  1
3   145702  1
4   547905  2
5   201991  3
6   88669   2
7   48909   2
8   36361   2
9   141726  2
10  1877020 3
11  374020  3

```java
Table table;
void setup(){
table = loadTable("HW 1 Data.csv", "header");

println(table.getRowCount() + " total rows in table");

for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    int product = row.getInt("Product");
    int sales = row.getInt("Sales");
    int category = row.getInt("Category");

    println(product + " (category " + category + ") has total sales of " + sales);
```

}
}

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. What exactly do you mean when you say you want to generate spheres based on data? What would that look like? Do you have any examples or mockup images? Have you written any code that draws a sphere? What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: i can load a sphere, but what I want is like a beach ball where it is divided by colors, each section can be represented by product which will have 10 sections or if I use category, I can have 3 sections.